# Como pasar un string a arreglo y unir ese arreglo en uno solo

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, objeto

Obtengo esta respuesta al usar flatten y hacer un split para convertir un stringa a array:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el método

```
 getAvailability(date: any) {
    this.bookingService.getAffiliateAvailability(this.doctor?.id, this.addressID, date)
      .subscribe(res => {
        if ((this.availableShcedules && this.availableShcedules.length > 0)) {
          this.availability = res;
          const { slots } = this.availability;
          //slots son el arreglo que contiene el rango de horas
          this.slots = slots;
          console.log(slots);
//array con flatten 
          _.flatten(slots).map((s: any) => {
            if (!s.available){
              this.available = true;
            }
            let str = moment(s.start).format('hh:mm A')
            this.timeList = str.split(',')
            console.log('array', this.timeList);
          })
        }
        else {
          this.attentionSchedules
        }
      }, (error => {
        console.error(error)
      }))
  }
```

¿Cómo puedo unir este respuesta de array en un solo Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.timeList` es un arreglo. Usa `push` de esta manera:

```javascript
    //...mas codigo
      _.flatten(slots).map((s: any) => {
            if (!s.available){
              this.available = true;
            }
            let str = moment(s.start).format('hh:mm A')
            //pop es para obtener el único valor del arreglo 
            this.timeList.push(str.split(',').pop())
            
          })
          //Y esto cambialo aca afuera para que te de el arreglo completo
          console.log('array', this.timeList);
          //.... mas código
```